# Collect information from many elements with identic class (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to collect name and price from things in ebay. For example I searched "armani", than I need to collect every item on first page using Selenium and append it to the list. But I have problem in my code:

```
mylist = list()
for a in driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='item3aeba8d9f0']/div"):
    name = a.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='item3aeba8d9f0']/div/div[2]/h3]")).getText()
    price = a.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='item3aeba8d9f0']/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[1]/span")).getText()
    mylist.append(name, price)
print(name)
```

The result should like: [[name, price],[name, price],...]

Comment: What is the "problem in my code"? The question should be specific... error message or description of the issue. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to append tuples to the list of the form (name, price).
Also you are attempting to iterate through a single web element when you want to iterate through a collection of web elements.

```
mylist = list()
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='item3aeba8d9f0']/div"): ##Change to .find_elements from .find_element
    name = a.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='item3aeba8d9f0']/div/div[2]/h3]")).getText()
    price = a.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='item3aeba8d9f0']/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[1]/span")).getText()
    mylist.append((name, price)) // THE CHANGE IS HERE!!!
    ##or you instead of tuples you could do a two element list.
    mylist.append([name, price]) // THE CHANGE IS HERE!!!
print(name)
```

Comment: the problem is in for loop.

Comment: @NurislomTuraev try changing the `driver.find_element_by_xpath("...")` to `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("...")`