# How to collect information from non identic classes. (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I want to collect information (name) from website like ebay and append it to the list. But I have a problem.
My code:

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_id("scroll"):
    name = a.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME(".market-name.market-link")).getText()
    mylist.append(name)
print(mylist)
```

Problem:

> name =
>   a.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME(".market-name.market-link")).getText()
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Whats wrong?

Html code (I have deleted unnecessary things, like picters, etc):

```
<div class="featured-item col-sxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 center-block app_730_2 item_17511241 has-wear scanned">
    <div>
        <a class="market-name market-link" href="=shop_view_item&amp;item=17511241">
        Happy
        </a>
        <div class="item-amount" onclick="showGraphFromId(17511241)">
        $0.04
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-orange" type="button" onclick="addToCart(17511241, 730, 4)">
        Add to Cart
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collect information from many elements with identic class (Selenium, Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377825/collect-information-from-many-elements-with-identic-class-selenium-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You use an incorrect By. `".market-name.market-link"` is Css Selector, not Class name.
   So you can solve this by change the `By.CLASS_NAME` to `By.CSS_SELECTOR`
2. `By.CLASS_NAME` is a first parameter of `find_element` and it is not a method, it is a value. The second parameter is an expression.

See code below.

```
try:
    name = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".market-name.market-link"))
    ).text
except:
    print("Can't find the text.")
```

Comment: what does it mean: 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .market-name.market-link ?

Comment: @NurislomTuraev it means there is no element on the page at the moment. Can you add HTML to your question?

Comment: @NurislomTuraev The Css Selector expression is correct. So I think it is because the `<a class="market-name market-link"...` is not present at the moment. I will update the answer to wait for it, please try. If it doesn't work, the link might be in an iframe.

Comment: Finally it worked, Thanks. But It appends only one item, not every item

Comment: @NurislomTuraev did you place my code in the for loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150457/discussion-between-nurislom-turaev-and-buaban).